# create variable from two data sas

Tags: if-statement, merge, sas

I am a beginner in SAS and I have two data sets that look like the following:

```
   A                                        B 
ID  Column1  Column 2  Column 4          ID  Column2   Column3 
1      A     carrot    food              1   carrot    veggie
1      B     carrot    drink             2   pear      fruit
2      A     pear      food              3   apple     fruit 
2      B     pear      drink
```

I would like to create a new variable called 'Column3' in A that uses the following logic:

```
If Column1 = A in dataset A, then set to Column3 from dataset B, otherwise set to Column4 in dataset A. 

   A                                         
ID  Column1  Column 2  Column 4   Column 3        
1      A     carrot    food       veggie         
1      B     carrot    drink      drink       
2      A     pear      food       fruit        
2      B     pear      drink      drink
```

The code I think would work:

```
DATA A;
    SET DF.A; 
    if (Column1 = A) then Column3 = [Column3 from B which I may have to merge];
else Column3 = Column4;
RUN;
PROC PRINT DATA = A; 
    TITLE 'OUTPUT DATASET'; 
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

So first merge the two datasets so that you have access to the values from the other dataset. Then you can use conditional logic to pick which variable to use to populate the new variable.  You will want to use a **NEW** variable instead of just using the variable you are pulling from B. If there are many observations in A matching to just one observation in B SAS will not change the value of column3 until it needs to read a new observation from B.

```
data want ;
  merge A B (keep=column2 column3);
  by column2 ;
  if column1 = 'A' then new_column3=column3;
  else new_column3=column4;
run;
```

Note that both datasets need to be sorted to be able to merge them.

I added the `KEEP=` dataset option because you listed both datasets as having a common non-key variable ID.  Not including ID in the list of variables read from B will prevent its values from overwriting the similarly named variable from dataset A.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple inner join as shown below.

```
  data have1;                                    
  input ID  Column1 $ Column2 $ Column4 $;   
 datalines;     
  1      A     carrot    food             
  1      B     carrot    drink            
  2      A     pear      food              
  2      B     pear      drink
  ;

data have2;
    input ID  Column2 $ Column3 $;
   datalines;
  1   carrot    veggie
  2   pear      fruit
  3   apple     fruit 
  ;

proc sql;
create table want as 
select a.id,
   a.column1,
   a.column2,
   a.column4, 
   case when trim(a.column1)= "A" 
       then b.column3 
       else a.column4
   end as column3
 from have1 a
 inner join 
 have2 b
 on a.id =b.id;
```

if you want in datastep use merge and use if statement.

```
proc sort data =have1;
by id;
run;

proc sort data =have2;
 by id;
 run;

 data want;
 merge have1(in=a) have2(in=b drop=column2);
 by id;
if a= 1 and b=1;
if trim(column1)= "A" then column3=column3;
else column3=column4;
run;
```

or you can use hash too.

```
data want;
if _n_ =1 then do;
 if _n_ = 0 then set have1 have2;
dcl hash h(multidata:"Y", dataset:"have2(drop=column2)");
h.definekey("id");
h.definedata( "column3");
h.definedone();
end;
set have1;
if h.find() = 0 then do until (h.find_next() ne 0);
end;
if trim(column1)= "A" then column3=column3;
else column3=column4;
run;
```